# Is there any impact if I give freeze-dry fish for dogs to my cat?

Tags: dogs, cats, diet, treats

My cat loves freeze-dry salmons. There's a particular brand of freeze-dry salmon for cats that my dad buys for her and she loves it. The pet shop that sells this treat ran out of stock of the cat's freeze-dry salmon, however they sell the exact same brand of freeze-dry salmon for dogs, in a package that looks exactly the same as the one for cats.

Before purchase, we asked the pet shop's assistant, who told us there's not much difference, as they are the same product from the same brand, and the difference is that the freeze-dry salmon that is meant for cats might be more salty than the freeze-dry salmon meant for dogs. After hearing this, we bought one packet for my cat, thinking less salt should be better for her instead.

We opened the new packet of freeze-dry salmon for dogs, and the only difference we spotted was the bite size of the treats; the smell, texture and crisp were the SAME. However, after one or two weeks of eating the treat meant for dogs, I noticed patches of fur had shed from both my cat's hind legs. Therefore, I bought freeze-dry chicken from another store, but she didn't like it as much.

Should I stop giving her the freeze-dried salmon that is meant for dogs?

[image: freeze-dry_01]
[image: freeze-dry_02]

Comment: Sounds really odd to me. Are you sure there's no other difference or cause for the shedding? I don't think just a slight difference in the amount of salt should cause such symptoms (that sounds like losing hair just because you don't get your daily dose of salted crackers).

Comment: Usually freeze dried treats is made out of 1 ingredient. In your case, it' salmon, IF this is the case then it shouldn't make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the manufacturer has a website you may be able to find the ingredients list for both versions there, or ask them this question.

It is possible that there's some difference in ingredients which she's allergic to; sometimes cats who are itchy will over-groom an area. And some cats do have allergies to some fish. It would be easy to stop giving this treat for a while and seeing if that makes a difference.

I should also note that over-grooming can be an indication that the animal is stressed for other reasons -- a "nervous habit" -- so you may want to think about whether anything else in her environment has changed recently.

As far as other recommendations goes: I have no idea what brands are available in Singapore, so I'd suggest you ask your vet

Comment: Yup, I can't find the website for the manufacturer. I had stopped giving her the treats and the fur on her both leg thighs actually grew back after 2 weeks. Last Sunday I had went to another pet store and bought a new freeze-dry white fish for cats, I am happy that she loves her new treats. Thanks a lot for the suggestions. =)